# AVALONIA: Refreshing the DataGrid when adding a row does not work correctly

Tags: wpf, datagrid, avalonia

I've already tried to rewrite this in many ways. I have the same wrong action every time.
I am using Avaloni version: 0.10.10
The code looks like this:
MainWindow.axaml:

```
                    <Button Content="Add New Device" Margin="5" Command="{Binding AddNewDevice}"/>
                    <DataGrid Items="{Binding Devices}" Grid.Row="1">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header=" IpAddress"
                                                Binding="{Binding IpAddress}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header=" Type"
                                                Binding="{Binding Type}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dpi"
                                                Binding="{Binding Dpi}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> AddNewDevice { get; }

        [Reactive]
        public ObservableCollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Devices = new ObservableCollection<Device>(new GetSettingsService().GetSettings().Devices);
            AddNewDevice = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
            {
                Devices.Add(
                    new Device()
                    {
                        IpAddress = "0.1.2.3",
                        Type = "TypeX"
                    });
            });
    }
```

And while adding the DataGrid it randomly works fine. For example, new lines appear only after clicking on an element and confirming it with the  key, or they appear but they are not visible only when scrolling, it turns out that they are "hidden" and the DataGrid does not expand when new elements appear.

What am I doing wrong? Or how to solve it?
I've tried to solve it differently but it always looks the same. DataGrid does not refresh properly after adding a new row.

Answer (score 0):

I also wasn't able to find a clean solution for this. I added the `VerticleAlignment="Stretch"` and `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` properties to the DataGrid which helps until the DataGrid fills up. If you get past the parent's height for rows then the scroll boxes act weirdly again. Sometimes not scrolling to the bottom or disappearing all together.

Other unsuccessful attempts were to subscribe to an event when my DataGrid Items list was updated then call `InvalidateVisual()`, `InvalidateMeasure()`, or `InvalidateArrange()` on either the DataGrid or its Parent component, but nothing would refresh the DataGrid.